Latin lyrics to "Far away"
I sing with a Japanese choir, and get asked to explain words in non-Japanese, in this case Latin. This is a (religious) song with words written by Robert Prizeman, former director of a boys choir in London, which you can read here: https://genius.com/Libera-far-away-lyrics
It includes a snippet of Latin, which resembles Veni Sancte Spiritus (Wikipedia article), but reads as:

Venite Spirituet emitte caelitusVenite SpirituVenite Spiritus

This seems to be a plural imperative "come", then "spirit" in some oblique case, "and" "bring forth from heaven", with a missing object... which looks as though he just deleted the next line of the original. This strikes me as a bit odd; and the other thing which strikes me as curious is the repetition of Spiritu in two different cases (abl and nom?) preceded by a plural verb. My question basically: is this "correct" Latin? Have I missed anything? (I did Latin at school, way over half a century ago, and I later learnt Italian.)

Venite Spiritu/
et emitte caelitus/
Venite Spiritu/
Venite Spiritus. Come ye in the spirit /and send thou from heaven / come ye in the spirit / come ye spirits. Creepy.

Is this your translation? You seem to render Spiritu as "spirit" and Spiritus as "Spirits", but how do you reconcile this with Latin grammar?

Spiritus is a fourth declension noun. Its nominative plural is spiritus with a long U. Spiritu is its ablative singular.

That looks like Latin written by someone who is pretty bad at Latin.

@OrangeDog Dunno. I'm not sure I could improve it much, assuming I was trying to say what I translated above. But then, why would I try to say that.

@Figulus well cmw's answer details the things that should be improved

@BrianChandler Are you sure that the lyrics match what's in the sheet music? The genius lyrics has at least one bad typo ("spirtus" for "spiritus")


This strikes me as a bit odd

Correct, it's not easily recognizable as grammatical. Because this is a hymn, I'd look to hymnal language to explain what's going on.
Remarks:
Spiritu is almost certainly meant to be the vocative, as in "come spirit" in the e.g. Veni Spiritus. The venite perhaps is taken/remembered from Venite hymn. The spurious form is probably created on analogy with Jesu, which is a fourth-declension vocative. The actual vocative, though, is spiritus, as the above link shows.
Maybe I'm being too uncharitable. It's possible that spiritu is rightly an ablative (see Figulus' comment), as in "come by means of the spirit", but I'm doubtful of this intention, since...
Emitte is singular. The alternation between plural and singular imperatives without a specifying a change in subject is what makes it look like patchwork Latin.
There's also either a missing object, as you note, though it is present in the Veni sancte. This misuse makes it even more likely this is patchwork Latin. [Edited: thanks brianpck!]
Caelitus is an adverb meaning "from heaven", from which the spirit would come. In the baptism of Jesus (Mark 1.9-11, John 1.32), "the spirit comes down from heaven like a dove" (Spiritum descendentem quasi columbam de caelo).
Add Figulus notes, spiritus could be nominative plural, ("come you spirits"), with a long -u- instead of a short one. If this is not just a mistake, then there's a lot of missing information that requires extra charity on the part of the reader. It's certainly no Adeste Fideles.

Maybe you are being uncharitable - That's what I thought when I first read your answer, but the more I think about it, the more I think you nailed it. The poet seems to be familiar with Jesu as the vocative of Jesus, and has extrapolated that pattern to Spiritus. Pity he doesn't seem to be familiar with Veni Sancte Spiritus, which shows the actual vocative of Sanctus Spiritus, and also conjugates venire correctly. I was probably being uncharitable when I called his composition creepy. Mea culpa.

Thanks. I allow for the possibility that this person didn't butcher it entirely, but I don't buy it yet! The Jesu was what I thought of as well (and I should make that analogy explicit).

Thanks - that was precisely my question: is it really Latin? I don't see any point in speculating what the writer intended to say (and he died fairly recently, I believe). The words are in a song, and we can't change them (except possibly to drop the final 's' on Spiritus, since final consonants are tricky for Japanese choirs). As a matter of fact, it is also quite common in singing Japanese popular songs to come across well-intentioned but ungrammatical bits of English, where the meaning really is not clear, but I just sing them anyway.

Re "emitte caelitus," this is clearly a callback to the medieval hymn Veni Sancte Spiritus (as mentioned by the OP), where the object of emitte is lucis tuae radium ("a ray of thy light").

@brianpck Right, but in the Veni Spiritus it has a direct object. More evidence it's just patchwork (pastiche?) and not real Latin.

@cmw I guess I was pushing back (mildly) on one of your suggestions: "...or he just chose the wrong word, a transitive verb instead of an intransitive one like evolo. My bet is on the latter." To me it's pretty clear this is a botched callback rather than a failure to find a better verb.

@brianpck I understand what you're getting at now. I agree --- edited!
